# Linker error on GLFW when trying to compile GLFW on Mac

Tags: c++, xcode, cocoa, linker, glfw

I'm trying to use glfw 2.7.5 on my mac with xcode but I'm getting the following errors:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_glfwGetKey", referenced from:
      Game::run() in Game.o
      RedScene::update(float, bool) in main.o
  "_glfwGetWindowParam", referenced from:
      Game::run() in Game.o
  "_glfwInit", referenced from:
      Window::Window() in Window.o
  "_glfwOpenWindow", referenced from:
      createWindow(int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int) in Window.o
  "_glfwOpenWindowHint", referenced from:
      Window::Window() in Window.o
  "_glfwPollEvents", referenced from:
      Game::run() in Game.o
  "_glfwSetKeyCallback", referenced from:
      createWindow(int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int) in Window.o
  "_glfwSetMouseButtonCallback", referenced from:
      createWindow(int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int) in Window.o
  "_glfwSetMousePosCallback", referenced from:
      createWindow(int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int) in Window.o
  "_glfwSetMouseWheelCallback", referenced from:
      createWindow(int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int) in Window.o
  "_glfwSetWindowTitle", referenced from:
      Window::setCaption(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&) in Window.o
  "_glfwSwapBuffers", referenced from:
      RedScene::update(float, bool) in main.o
  "_glfwSwapInterval", referenced from:
      createWindow(int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int) in Window.o
  "_glfwTerminate", referenced from:
      Window::~Window() in Window.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I've read this [Problems using GLFW and XCode : won't compile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9250961/problems-using-glfw-and-xcode-wont-compile) and several other links on the internet but I can't find a solution.

I've set the Cocoa framework, the OpenGL framework and libglfw.a (which I compiled using "sudo make cocoa-install"), in the linker flags I set -lgflw and I'm building for 32-bit Intel. At first I was building for a 64-bit but I think GLFW doesn't support that on Mac yet (I was getting joystick file errors), the error changes when I compile for 32-bit and it can't find the functions I'm using. Any idea what I could do to fix this?

Comment: When you built `libglfw.a` did you build it for 32 bit or 64 bit ? Use `file libglfw.a` to check that it's 32 bit.

Comment: It's 64 bit (I had to use "lipo -info" instand of "file".) Is there a way to make it to 32 bit from a 64 bit machine?

Comment: You need to look at the README, docs, makefile or whatever for libglfw to see how to build a 32 bit version. Alternatively you could just build your app as 64 bit instead of 32 bit.

Comment: GLFW doesn't support 64 bit mac yet. I'll look into bulding the 32 bit version. If you make an answer I'll accept it, thanks for the help :)

Comment: No problem - I've put together an answer below in which I've added some further suggestions.

Comment: @LukeB Did you ever get your problems sorted? Seems to me like he just made an answer and you accepted it out of kindness which is unfortunate for people looking for the actual answer.

Comment: @PladniusBrooks Its been over a year since I asked the question, so my memory could be betraying me, but if I recall correctly my problem was solved by building libglfw.a as 32-bit. So his answer is correct. If you feel like something else can be added to this problem, feel free to answer it too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely you have built libglfw.a for 64 bit and so you get link errors when you try to use it in a 32 bit app. You can either rebuild libglfw.a for 32 bit (or as a "fat" 32 bit and 64 bit library), or you could just build your app as 64 bit.

Note that in recent version of Mac OS X and Xcode, gcc builds 64 bit code by default, so you need to specify `-m32` on the command line to get 32 bit code. How you do this in practice depends on the makefile for libglfw.a - there may well be an `ARCH` or other symbol that you can specify on the command line to force a 32 bit build.